# How can/should I include Ruby project file dependencies in config/environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, dependencies, environment

New Rubyist here. In my lectures on Ruby, I've come across various tricks/shortcuts for adding file dependencies to the `config/environment` file so that one's program runs smoothly. It has been unclear to me which of these, when combined, are redundant; which are best practices; and which are completely useless and/or wrong and should be done the long way. Clarification would be appreciated!

The ones I've come across:

- `require_relative "../lib/test1.rb"`
- `: << '.' & require "lib/test1.rb"`
- `: << '.' & Dir['lib/*.rb'].each {|f| require f}`
- `require File.dirname(__FILE__)`
- ["require-all" gem](https://github.com/jarmo/require_all)

Feel free to include other ways, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config/environment.rb` is a file that the Rails framework itself has opinions about.  Over the lifetime of your application, you will be positively incented not to modify this file (if you can avoid it).  This will allow for the easiest possible upgrade path.  Consider placing your initialization in a file in `config/initializers`.

If your code alters the behavior of Rails itself in such a fundamental way that placement in `config/initializers` loses its potency, or if the long-term maintenance of your code is not a concern, I'll consider the above.  Items 2+3 work by appending to your `LOAD_PATH`, which I would not recommend, let alone calling a best practice.  (Adding `RAILS_ROOT/config` may not be a major issue by default, but you might create some very difficult to debug errors.)

The location of `config/environment.rb` hasn't changed in a long time, so relative requirement (i.e. option #1) is probably fine.  `require File.dirname(__FILE__)` by itself does nothing (you're requiring a directory) but is worthwhile to remember in an approach like `require File.join[File.dirname(__FILE__), '../lib/your_file.rb']` which will work the same regardless of load path, or working directory concerns.  This is what I would do.

I would not use a gem for this, since the behavior of the gem could change in unpredictable ways, and you're already in an area where Rails can make your choices inconvenient.